# Discrete Mathematics how to prove $(A\setminus B)\setminus C ⊆ A\setminus (B\setminus C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I can't figure out how to prove this one. Help please
how to prove $(A\setminus B)\setminus C ⊆ A\setminus(B\setminus C)$
in which prove system to choose?

Comment: How about drawing a Venn diagram?

Comment: Hint: Compare both with $A\setminus B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that if $D\subset E$ then $A$ \ $E \subset A $\ $D.$ Therefore as $B$ \ $C \subset B,$ we  have  $$A \backslash B\subset A \backslash (B \backslash C).$$ And obviously $$(A \backslash B)\backslash C\subset A\backslash B.$$

Answer (score 2):

An element in $(A\setminus B)\setminus C$ belongs to $A\setminus B$, so in particular it belongs to $A$.

On the other hand it doesn't belong to $B$, so it doesn't belong to $B\setminus C$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$(A-B)-C=A \cap (B' \cap C')$$

$$A-(B-C)=A \cap (B' \cup C)$$

Now note that $(B' \cap C') \subseteq B' \subseteq (B' \cup C)$ for completing the proof.